# How to determine start of week with php?

Tags: php, date

I have a script which gets the monday of the week to be able to display a calendar by using a while loop, so it gets the monday of that week then list out 7 divs which correspond to a day of the week.

I thought it was working but today(sunday) it has start listing the week starting tomorrow(monday) why is this? the code I have is:

```
$days = date("j",strtotime("monday this week"));
```

That variable returns 8, meaning PHP thinks the week starts on a sunday?

Comment: maybe the week starts on Sunday ?

Comment: you may need to clarify you question better. First you say you want the week to start on monday, then you say it's not working because it starts listing the week on monday. So which is it?

Comment: @ionutvmi Yes, it does. It's indexed from 0 (sunday) to 6 (saturday).

Comment: `returns 8` 8 of december is monday and the start of the week!

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: I think what OP means is: he want's the date from the monday this week! So 01.12.2014 but he gets 09.12.2'14 from next week! right?

Comment: maybe something like this date("j",strtotime("last sunday") + 60*60*24) ?

Comment: So how would I start the week on monday and not having it think that the new week has begun once it's sunday?

Comment: @ElliottCoe is my answer that what your looking for? Otherwise please explain yourself more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo $monday = date("j",strtotime('last monday', strtotime('tomorrow')));
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are better of relying on [ISO8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```php
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-j');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/231703)</kbd>